# MongoDB concurrent update (with sub collection)

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, collections, concurrency, updates

I started using MongoDB (With spring-data-mongo) at work and so fare all good.
But I was wondering how does MongoDB deals with occurrent update? And more specifically what are the best practices to handle these ?

For example I have a Document that contains a Map

```
@Document(collection = "test)
public class Test {
   private String name;
   private Map<Long, Holder> myMap;
}

public class Holder {
   private List<Integer> list;
}


{ 
  "name": "test",
  "myMap: "{"1":"{"list":[1,2,3]}", "2":"{"list":[1,2,3]}"}"
}

Thread A: retrieves the Test Document
Thread A: gets myMap and add a new entry in the list for key "1"
Thread B: retrieves the Test Document
Thread B: gets myMap and add a new entry in the list for key "1"
Thread B: saves the Test Document
Thread A: saves the Test Document
```

The question is what will be in the myMap ? the entry added by B or A ? or both ?

Comment: It depends on the underlying MongoDB commands used, [update()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) or [findAndModify()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/).

Comment: in this case ( I'm using spring repositories)
repository.findOne(id)
...
repository.save(document);

Comment: I'm not sure of the internals of `repository.save()`. For finer grain control on the update operation, you have to look into [methods for the Update class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongodb-template-update.update), or using atomic updates with [`findAndModify()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html#d0e2644).

Comment: Let's say i'm using findAndModify(), is there a way to "add" (and not entirely replace) an entry in the myMap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$push` array update operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) with either `update()` or `findAndUpdate()`.

Assuming an object like

```
{ name : "test", myMap : {
    "1" : { list : [1,2,3] },
    "2" : { list : [4,5,6] }
}}
```

you can simply do

```
update(..., { $push:{ "myMap.2.list" : 8 }})    // results in "2" : {list:[4,5,6,8]}
update(..., { $push:{ "myMap.3.list" : 9 }})    // results in new entry "3" : {list:[9]}
```

This will either append the value to the existing entry array or create a new entry (with a new array).

From the docs:

> The $push operator appends a specified value to an array.
>
> If the field is absent in the document to update, $push adds the array field with the value as its element.

For completion, you should check out the docs of other [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) like `$set`, `$inc`, `$max`, etc.

---

If you simply use

```
update(..., { name : "test", myMap : {
    "1" : { list : [1,2,3] },
    ...
})
```

in both threads, the result won't be specified and will depend on which update request gets executed last.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know myMap.2 could be use (with the dot) to specify to which key append the object. I have slighlyt modified my question with a more complete model. what would the set look like ? myMap.2.list ?

Comment: @Johny19, I have also updated the answer accordingly.